# CSS Grid have first two rows take up 100vh with one row auto sized

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout using grid where the first two rows of the grid take up `100vh`, but the navbar is sticky with an unknown height. The third row is then the body content, which can be scrolled to.

The initial layout can be achieved easily enough, without sticky, but for the `position: sticky` to work with the navbar, all the elements need to be at the same level. I don't want to rely on a static height for the navbar.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#layout {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

nav {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: sticky;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

p {
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
  padding-block: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <header>Hero</header>
  <nav>Sticky navbar</nav>
</div>

<p>Content you need to scroll down to see</p>
<p>More contnet</p>
<p>Even more contnet</p>
<p>So much contnet</p>
<p>wow</p>
```

So basically, is there any way to achieve this sort of layout without specifying a height for the navbar?

Answer (score 0):

Make the sticky element top AND bottom then you can have all the element inside the body:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

p {
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
  padding-block: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>Hero</header>
<nav>Sticky navbar</nav>
<p>Content you need to scroll down to see</p>
<p>More contnet</p>
<p>Even more contnet</p>
<p>So much contnet</p>
<p>wow</p>
```